# LVM: migrate pv data to another pv at same lv

Tags: lvm

- First:

  ```
  pvcreate /dev/sdb(1GB)
  vgcreate vg1 /dev/sdb
  lvcreate -n lv1 -l 100%FREE vg1
  ```

  then mount to `/data`
- Second:

  1. upload 500MB file to `/data`
  2. add 3GB disk, create pv (`/dev/sdc`) and add it to `vg1`
  3. upload 1GB file to `/data`

Now:

- 2 physical volumes (`/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`)
- 1 volume group (`/dev/vg1`)
- 1 logical volume (`/dev/vg1/lv1`)
- mount at `/data` contains 1.5GB file

Question: how to migrate `/dev/sdb` data to `/dev/sdc` to remove physical volume `/dev/sdb`?

Desired result:

- 1 physical volume (`/dev/sdc`, 3GB)
- 1 volume group (`/dev/vg1`)
- 1 logical volume (`/dev/vg1/lv1`)
- mount at `/data` contains 1.5GB file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "empty" a physical volume with `pvmove` so in your case `pvmove /dev/sdb` will move all allocated extents from `sdb` to `sdc`. After that you can remove `sdb` from the volume group with `vgreduce vg1 /dev/sdb`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will try

Comment: I got 'No extents available for allocation'.then I add third disk 10GB create pv add to vg1 then run pvmove /dev/sdb /dev/sdd  system restart  and hangs  I poweroff it  when start  I edit start options add init=/bin/bash  then  I type /usr/sbin/lvm and run pvmove /dev/sdb /dev/sdd  got success  but next run /pvmove /dev/sdc /dev/sdd failed

Comment: Please add `pvs` output to the question. If `sdb` has 1 GB and `sdc` 3 GB you should have enough free space for the `pvmove`.